# Linux check user input error handling

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I commented the things I have problem. 
and also, is there any other way I can exit my loop without using the exit command?.................

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "$done" != "true" ] #this don't work
do

    echo "Please enter one of the following options"
    echo "1. Move empty files"
    echo "2. Check file size"
    echo "3. Which file is newer"
    echo "4. File check rwx"
    echo "5. Exit".
    echo -n "Enter Choice: "
    read scale # starting from this part for checking if user only inputs numbers 1-5 not working
    if ! [[ "$scale" =~ ^[0-6]+$ ]]
        then
        echo "Invalid Input"
    fi #up to this part is not working

    read -r answer
    case "$answer" in
     1)  ./move_empty 
            exit 55
            ;;
     2)  ./file_size 
        exit 0           
            ;;
     3) ;;
         ;; 
      4) 
        ;;
      5) done="true";;
esac
done
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few things Which should be avoided

- `while [ "$done" != "true" ]` --> `while [ $done -ne 1 ]` /* -ne is not equal to */
- `case "$answer" in`  --> `case $answer in`

Complete Code

```
var=0
flag=1
while [ $var -ne 1 ]
do
echo "Please enter one of the following options"
echo "1. Move empty files"
echo "2. Check file size"
echo "3. Which file is newer"
echo "4. File check rwx"
echo "5. Exit".
echo -n "Enter Choice: "
read scale
if   [ $scale -gt 0 -a $scale -lt 6 ]
    then
    echo "valid Input, you can procees for switch "
    else
    echo "invalid input.. go again & give correct one "
        flag=0
fi

if [ $flag -eq 1 ]
then
read -r answer
case $answer in
         1)  ./move_empty
                #exit 55
                break
             ;;
         2)  ./file_size
                #exit 0
                break
                 ;;
         3)
                exit 0
                ;;
        4)
                ;;
        5) done="true";;
esac
fi
done
```

To come out from loop, without using `exit` command, use `break`. Here is the answer from `man 1 bash`

> break [n]
>                 Exit from within a for, while, until,  or  select  loop.
>                 If n is specified, break n levels.  n must be ≥ 1.  If n
>                 is greater than  the  number  of  enclosing  loops,  all
>                 enclosing  loops  are  exited.   The  return  value is 0
>                 unless n is not greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Hello achal, this " while [ $done -ne 1 ] " doesn't work too.. it says [: -ne: unary operator expected

Comment: None of these address the problem with `read`. The first two are just style comments, and I don't even know what you mean by the third.

Comment: @Grace I modified, let me know  if it helps

Comment: @achal sorry it still won't work for me. It stop the whole script immediately. I wanted to happen is if the user enter number '5' the script will stop/exit but not using exit command

Comment: @Grace try the `break` command. This will break from the loop without exiting.  Also, I don't agree with removing the `"`s from the variables: the `"` should stay unless you need to split/glob, which it does not seem like you do.

Comment: @Grace and if you do go with the `break`, you can change the while loop to: `while true` for simplicity.

Comment: after I added the break my script for checking user only input numbers 1-5 won't work

Comment: @Grace  I modified again,Its works in my system, hope it works for you.

Comment: @achal it works for the error handling but proceeding to my case it wont work

Comment: Have you created `move_empty` and `file_size` binaries @Grace

Comment: @Grace Its entering into case and not executing or something else ?

Comment: @achal its not executing the codes inside my case. It stops after saying Valid Input

Comment: Is it entering into case @Grace

Comment: It works for me as I created binary called `move_empty` by `gcc try.c -o move_empty` and then I executed above script as `sh grace.sh` and I entered  1 as `answer` and it executed `move_empty`